# React VS NextJS for Django

Tags: reactjs, django, next.js, frontend

I am still quite new to React, and I am currently working on a Django-React app. I read a bit about Next JS and it seems quite useful and interesting (especially for SEO), but I've heard various opinons about it. I am considering using it for the front end and rendering only.

Therefore I was wondering, would it be worth it to learn and implement NextJS (and re do some of the work I did with react), or is the effort to great for a minimal result? Will NextJS allow me to do more than react (in terms of SEO and rendering)? Does the complexity of a project really increases when implementing Nextjs + React-Django?

Lots of people are talking about NextJs and I was wondering if it was just "another framework" or really something more.

Have a good day

Answer (score 3):

Nextjs is better for SEO as it renders server side and all the data can be indexed by search engines.  IMO Nextjs is better because you are strictly using Javascript and it integrates very well with react.  If you have good design patterns/reusable react components it will be very easy to integrate with Nextjs.  The built in API feature is also very seemless.  If you use Nextjs there is no need for Django.

Comment: Interesting ! However I saw many tutorial/projects where developers used both django and nextJs, what would be the benefits of using only nextjs (in terms of resilience/quality of code) ?

Comment: You can still use Django if you don't like using Node.  Quality of code depends on how it's written, size of application, etc.  Think of Nextjs as an all in one type framework that gives you the flexibility of frontend and backend processes to display data on the webpage.  Django may be better in certain use cases.  It all depends on your requirements.